# Are documentation requests on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I've recently commented a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1129147/where-is-the-documentation-for-all-sublime-text-3-preference-settings-commands-a) being off-topic asking for software / product / service recommendation.

The OP commented he thinks it's on-topic as it's not "software / product / service"

I believe those are off-topic:

- even if they aren't subjective, they require link only answers and links can broke / change at any time
- majority of documentations aren't hidden on the web, if you can't find them by a google search then there is a high chance they don't exist, in this case we can't help, best to contact the developer / owner.

Are documentation requests on-topic on superuser.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation comes under learning material - if not. I'd close that question as too broad.